# Is there a way to pass keys into a JavaScript array where a a string might match multiple values of an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, key

So, if I have only one key to match, then something like:

```
    var str = "foo";

    let [key,val] = Object.entries(obj).find(([key,val]) => val== str);
    return key;
```

would work beautifully. But is there a way to add multiple keys if the value matches?

To give example of an object that might match the above string:

```
    obj = {
      quay: "foo",
      key1: "blargh",
      yaya: "foo",
      idnet: "blat",
      blah: "foo",
      hahas: "blargh"
    }
```

What I want to do is return all of the "foo" keys (`quay`, `yaya`, and `blah`) based on the matching var `str` from above.

I'm sure the answer is something simple I'm overlooking.

Comment: Please try: `const keysArray = Object.entries(obj).filter(([, v]) => (v === str)).map(([k]) => k);` and share your feedback.

Comment: Upvoted out of sheer gratitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` instead of `find` and `map` to remove the values.

```js
const obj = { quay: "foo", key1: "blargh", yaya: "foo", idnet: "blat", blah: "foo", hahas: "blargh" }

const str = 'foo';

const keys = Object.entries(obj).filter(([, val]) => val === str).map(([key]) => key);
console.log(keys);
```

Comment: beat me to it by 15 seconds. Awesome. :-)

Comment: @jsN00b I guess, I saw the question earlier and had more time.

Comment: You can use `[, val]` to destructure the 2nd item (`val`) only.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.keys()` to get an array of keys, and filter them with `Array.filter()`. In the filter's predicate function take the relevant value from the object using the key - `obj[key]` and compare it to `str`.

```js
const str = 'foo'

const obj = {"quay":"foo","key1":"blargh","yaya":"foo","idnet":"blat","blah":"foo","hahas":"blargh"}

const keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] === str)

console.log(keys)
```

Comment: This was an excellent solution, but unfortunately didn't work for the actual code I was applying it to (not the example). That being the case, I still upvoted this answer because it's bound to be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the entries like you are doing, but instead of using find, filtering all the entries with the value on `str` that you want to find and mapping it to a list. Like this:

```js
const str = "foo";

const obj = {
  quay: "foo",
  key1: "blargh",
  yaya: "foo",
  idnet: "blat",
  blah: "foo",
  hahas: "blargh"
}

const repeated = Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([key, val]) => val === str)
  .map(([key, val]) => key);

console.log(repeated);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```js
const obj = {
  quay: "foo",
  key1: "blargh",
  yaya: "foo",
  idnet: "blat",
  blah: "foo",
  hahas: "blargh"
}
let items = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, val]) => val === 'foo'));
console.log(Object.keys(items))
```